# TableView and image circle

Tags: image, uitableview, swift, uiimage

I have a standard TableView in Swift. I want a circled image on the left. Here is the code to define the cell:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    // Edit image
    println("HEIGHT: " + toString(cell.imageView.frame.size.height)) // PRINTS 0.0 ! Why?
    let imageViewSize = 70 as CGFloat
    cell.imageView.image = self.items[indexPath.row].bgImage // my image UIImage
    cell.imageView.frame.size.height = imageViewSize
    cell.imageView.frame.size.width = imageViewSize
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
 ...
```

}

So I get the image on the left, but: in my case (with the cell's height I defined in the storyboard), if I put 70 for the imageViewSize, I get the right circle I want, but with no margin with the circled image of the row below/above. And for instance, if I put imageViewSize=50, then I have a square with rounded corners --> I would have expected a smaller circled image.

I would like to "play" with the imageViewSize to reduce the image's size and therefore increase the margin.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the `frame` struct element by element. You have to change it and reassign it.

```
var frame = cell.imageView.frame
let imageSize = 70 as CGFloat
frame.size.height = imageSize
frame.size.width  = imageSize
cell.imageView.frame = frame 
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageSize / 2.0
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

You might have to adjust `origin.x` and `origin.y` as well.

As discussed, you may be better off subclassing `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: With your code, the behavior is the same. If I change imageSize to 50, the image is now a square with rounded corners, not a circle anymore (with imageSize = 70). Am I missing something?

Comment: You must be. I tested this in Playground, and changing the image size does indeed result in another size. The solution: subclass `UITableViewCell` and insert your own image view. The original `UITableViewCell` image view has some known quirks like this.